# How do I determine whether traits in a subgroup of a big group are significantly different than the traits in the whole group in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have a big group of 1052 people. Out of 18 people with trait A 11 people also have trait B.
Out of the whole group of 1052 people 569 have trait B.

How do I determine in R whether the trait B is significantly different distributed in people with trait A compared to the overall population?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two ways: Chi-square and logistic regression.

Chi square would be used if you don't think either A or B is a dependent or independent variable. In R

```
traitA <- c(rep('Yes', 18), rep('No', 1052-18))
traitB <- c(rep("Yes", 11), rep("No", 7), rep('Yes', 569), rep("No", 1052-569-18))

chisq.test(traitA, traitB)
```

Logistic regression would be if you think that (say) B is a dependent variable:

```
m1 <- glm(traitB=='Yes'~as.factor(traitA), family = 'binomial')
summary(m1)
```